# Ruby on rails wrong number of arguments

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, search, arguments

my code for search:controller:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @index=self.index(params:[:search])
  end
end
```

view:

```
<center>
<h2> Search </h2>

<form id=”search-form” name=”search” method=”get” action=”index.html”>

<input id=”s” type=”text” name=”s” placeholder=”Search…”>

<input id=”search-button-1″ type=”submit” name=”search-button-1″>

</form>
```

model

```
class Welcome < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.search(search)
        if search
         where('name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
        else
         scoped
        end
   end
end
```

can you please help me and let me know where I am going wrong,I am getting a `wrong number of arguments error` and I am new to Ruby on rails, can someone please help.

Comment: At least one issue is the `:` after `params`. It's unclear what `self.index` is supposed to be other than an infinite recursive loop, it should be `Welcome.search` with the search param.

Comment: The stack trace which accompanies the error will point you to the offending line of code:  look for the first line which is in your project folder (as opposed to one of the gem classes/modules)

Comment: Why are different users editing the code in the **question**? Also, please do not remove indentation when you edit (within if, else).

Answer (score 2):

I think your controller should be:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @index = Welcome.search(params[:search])
  end
end
```

Comment: undefined local variable or method `welcome' for #<WelcomeController:0x007fd53652ba30> is the error i get when I try this ,where should I define welcome ?

Comment: Did you capitalize "Welcome" in your code?  Ruby is case sensitive. Welcome is defined as your class, "welcome" isn't.

Comment: no errors now, but the search logic does nt seem to work as yet... no change in the page, when I type a word in the search section and hit enter...

Comment: Your input text's name is "s" then you will get it with "params[:s]".

Comment: what should the input text name be to search for any word on the page or something of that sort, i tried using "all" somehow did nt work..

Comment: If you need to use "params[:search]" change <input id=”s” type=”text” name=”s” placeholder=”Search…”> to <input id=”s” type=”text” name=”search” placeholder=”Search…”>